# Yum problem on Centos 6.7

Tags: linux, centos, yum, upgrade, segmentation-fault

I have installed php, mysql, httpd on my vps. But when I try upgrade php via yum I get the following error.

```
[root@ns1 home]# yum --enablerepo=remi update php

Package(s) php available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for Update
```

Then I am trying to install it with the following command but I get a "Segmentation fault".

```
[root@ns1 home]# yum --enablerepo=remi install php"
```

Yum update without a package is also not working:

```
[root@ns1 home]# yum update

Freeing read locks for locker 0x1ab: 23312/140158884435712
Freeing read locks for locker 0x1ad: 23312/140158884435712
Freeing read locks for locker 0x1b3: 23312/140158884435712
Freeing read locks for locker 0x1b4: 23312/140158884435712
Freeing read locks for locker 0x1b5: 23312/140158884435712
Freeing read locks for locker 0x1b6: 23312/140158884435712
```

I tried to clean cache but no luck.

```
cd /var/lib

rm __db*

rpm --rebuilddb
```

I waiting for your suggestions guys. 
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I don't understand your problem discription...

Comment: Yum is not working!!!

Comment: Yes, I do understand, that you have a problem with yum. What happens, when you just run`yum upgrade`?

Comment: i have installed php 
[root@ns1 home]# php -v
PHP 5.4.36 (cli) I couldn't upgrade php via yum. Yum gives me this error Package(s) php available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for Update

Comment: you are missing the main point!

Comment: So the package php is not installed (doesn't mean php is not installed), but where is the mentioned segfault?

Comment: [root@ns1 home]# yum --enablerepo=remi install php" and getting that one "Segmentation fault".

Comment: Why do you have double quotes at the end of the command?

Answer (score 1):

It has been suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/644205/why-wont-yum-install-updates) that it may be a lack of memory on the VPS and to try to resolve the issue by either shutting down running services or add a swap file. Then run

```
package-cleanup --cleandupes
```

prior to running other updates.  One comment stated that stopping httpd service to do the yum updates worked.